# Logical error while implementing shared preference

Tags: android

I have a activity called main,another is signin and settings.If i am logged in i save my userid and from next time the app opens from my home activity.In home activity i have button named settings.In settings there is a button names signout and by pressing that it takes the user to SignIn activity page.But the problem is when i press back button the app should have closed all the activity as i have called system.exit(1) instead it takes me to home activity

## session manager

```
    SharedPreferences pref;

    // Editor for Shared preferences
    Editor editor;

    // Context
    Context _context;

    // Shared pref mode
    int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

    // Sharedpref file name
    private static final String PREF_NAME = "AndroidHivePref";

    // All Shared Preferences Keys
    private static final String IS_LOGIN = "IsLoggedIn";

    // User name (make variable public to access from outside)
    public static final String KEY_ID = "id";

    // Email address (make variable public to access from outside)
   // public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";

    // Constructor
    public SessionManager(Context context){
        this._context = context;
        pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = pref.edit();

    }


    public void createLoginSession(String id){
        // Storing login value as TRUE
        editor.putBoolean(IS_LOGIN, true);

        // Storing name in pref
        editor.putString(KEY_ID, id);

        // Storing email in pref
       // editor.putString(KEY_EMAIL, email);

        // commit changes
        editor.commit();
    }   

    /**
     * Check login method wil check user login status
     * If false it will redirect user to login page
     * Else won't do anything
     * */
    public boolean checkLogin(){
        // Check login status
        if(!this.isLoggedIn()){

            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }

    }



    /**
     * Get stored session data
     * */
    public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails(){
        HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
        // user name
        user.put(KEY_ID, pref.getString(KEY_ID, null));

        // user email id
        //user.put(KEY_EMAIL, pref.getString(KEY_EMAIL, null));

        // return user
        return user;
    }

    /**
     * Clear session details
     * */
    public void logoutUser(){
        // Clearing all data from Shared Preferences
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();

     // After logout redirect user to Login Activity
        Intent i = new Intent(_context, SignInActivity.class);

        // Closing all the Activities
//        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
//         
//        // Add new Flag to start new Activity
//        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        // Staring Login Activity
        _context.startActivity(i);
    }


    /**
     * Quick check for login
     * **/
    // Get Login State
    public boolean isLoggedIn(){
        return pref.getBoolean(IS_LOGIN, false);
    }
```

## SignIN

```
    TextView forgetPassword,newAccount,guest;
    EditText emailEditText,passwordEditText;
    private Button signIn;



    private  int user_check=1;
    private Editor editor;
    SessionManager session;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signin);

        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

        emailEditText=(EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.emailEditText);

        passwordEditText=(EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.passwordEditText);

        //forgetPassword= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.signup);
        newAccount= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.signup);

        signIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signInButton);
        guest=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.guest);

        newAccount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i=new Intent(SignInActivity.this, SignUpActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

        signIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                SignInModel signInModel = new SignInModel();

                String email = emailEditText.getText().toString().trim();
                String password = passwordEditText.getText().toString().trim(); 


                if(FormHelper.isValidEmail(email) )
            {
                signInModel.setEmail(email);
                signInModel.setPassword(password);

                //Utility.showMessage(SignInActivity.this, signInModel.getEmail()+" "+signInModel.getPassword());

                if(haveNetworkConnection()==true)
                {

                new SignInTask(SignInActivity.this,signInModel).execute();

                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "Check Your Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

//              if(signInModel.getStatus()==true)
//              {
////                    Intent i=new Intent(SignInActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
////                    i.putExtra("user_check",1 );
////                    startActivity(i);
//                  //finish();
//                  
//              }
//              else
//              {
//                  Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "Enter valid email and password",Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
//                  
//              }
//              
//              
//              //finish();
//              
            }
            else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "Enter  email and password",Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                }







            }
        });



        guest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

//              editor.putInt(user_check, 0);
//              editor.apply();



                Intent i=new Intent(SignInActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("user_check",0 );
                startActivity(i);
                finish();


            }
        });

    }



    public void signInDataLoaded(SignInModel signIn)
    {
        //Utility.showMessage(this, signIn.getStatus()+" "+signIn.getUserId());


        if(signIn.getStatus()==true)
        {
            //Utility.showMessage(this, "Login Successfull! User: "+signIn.getUserId());

            //SessionManager.getCurrrentSession().setCurrentUser(signIn.getUserId());  

//          Intent i=new Intent(SignInActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
//          startActivity(i);
//          finish();
            session.createLoginSession(signIn.getUserId());

            Intent i=new Intent(SignInActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("user_check",1 );
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "Enter valid email and password",Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();

        }



    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    private boolean haveNetworkConnection() {
        boolean haveConnectedWifi = false;
        boolean haveConnectedMobile = false;

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
        for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
            if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
                if (ni.isConnected())
                    haveConnectedWifi = true;
            if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
                if (ni.isConnected())
                    haveConnectedMobile = true;
        }
        return haveConnectedWifi || haveConnectedMobile;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) { //Back key pressed
           //Things to Do
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(SignInActivity.this);

            // Setting Dialog Title
            alertDialog.setTitle("Confirm Exit...");

            // Setting Dialog Message
            alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?");

            // Setting Icon to Dialog
            alertDialog.setIcon(drawable.cancel);

            // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {

                // Write your code here to invoke YES event
               // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on YES", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                      System.exit(1);
                }
            });

            // Setting Negative "NO" Button
            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // Write your code here to invoke NO event
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on NO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            // Showing Alert Message
            alertDialog.show();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

signinorout is my logout button

## settings

```
signInOrOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                // SessionManager.getCurrrentSession().setCurrentUser(null);
                session.logoutUser();
                Intent i=new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, SignInActivity.class);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                // Add new Flag to start new Activity
               i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });
```

In my home activity i haven't finished the activity but i have cleared all my previous activities in settings Intent.flag_activity_clear_top

Answer (score 0):

```
   Intent i = new Intent(_context, SignInActivity.class);

    // Closing all the Activities
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    // Add new Flag to start new Activity
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    // Staring Login Activity
    _context.startActivity(i);
```

You should uncomment second and third lines for this.

Comment: i actually called them in my settings.check.@orest

Comment: Why don't you add FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK ?

Comment: i have added that though the problem is same @Orest